# Unwanted breakpoints in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I check out my projects from SVN and usually have a couple of projects in my solution while debugging . sometimes when I set breakpoints in my program to debug it, the program breaks at other points that I have Not set any break point in there at all ! but there is a break point in there?
How is it happening? does VS keep its breakpoints location in the .sln file of each project and when I check out from SVN, it causes to break on breakpoint that other people have set on that project? or something else is causing it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have more than the SLN file in source control. If you blindly add your entire folder structure to source control, you will get unwanted behavior.

Comment: Hmm, so it is reading the breakpoint from the SLN file of each project. and I have not added the SLN to the ignore list of SVN.  that explains it. thanks.

Comment: Well, I think you want your SLN file in source control in case new projects get added. Did the .suo file get added to source control?

Comment: hmm, now I looked again,  both .sln and .suo are in Ignore list of SVN

Answer (score 1):

These could be **exceptions** as the debugger would force a break if an unhandled exception occurs.

Comment: but at the line that it breaks, there is that big red circle that we use to set the break point.